# How to set up correlated query in cognos framework manager

Tags: cognos, correlated-subquery

Need some help here.
I have a query like following. How should I set up in cognos framework? or, how can I turn into (multiple) simple query. So then I can set up as which I did for other query?

```
SELECT 
  isnull((SELECT  distinct   'Y'
  FROM 
  PC  WITH(NOLOCK) 
  join P WITH(NOLOCK) on  PC.POSTN_ID = P.ROW_ID and P.PR_EMP_ID=E.PER_ID
  join  CE WITH(NOLOCK) on  CE.PAR_ROW_ID=P.EMP_ID and E.PER_ID=CE.PAR_ROW_ID 
  where  PC.X_RESEARCH='Y' and PC.CON_ID=F.ROW_ID
  ) ,'N') X_RESEARCH,
  F.ROW_ID,
  E.ROW_ID A
   FROM
   F INNER JOIN G ON (G.CON_ID=dbo.S_CONTACT.ROW_ID)
   INNER JOIN E ON (E.ROW_ID=G.ACTIVITY_ID)
```

I have imported physical models already and just need to see how to do it in the logic model
Thanks very much!

Comment: You could shorten that SQL to 

`SELECT 
  'Y' X_RESEARCH
, F.ROW_ID
, E.ROW_ID A
FROM F
  INNER JOIN G ON G.CON_ID = dbo.S_CONTACT.ROW_ID
  INNER JOIN E ON E.ROW_ID = G.ACTIVITY_ID`

but it still wouldn't work because dbo.S_CONTACT is not included.  You'll also have a problem with the cartesian join.  (F doesn't join to anything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took another look.  My previous comment was not accurate.

I can boil your query down to something that's a little easier to read:

```
SELECT coalesce(XR.X_RESEARCH, 'N') as X_RESEARCH
, F.ROW_ID
, E.ROW_ID A

FROM F
  INNER JOIN G ON G.CON_ID = dbo.S_CONTACT.ROW_ID
  INNER JOIN E ON E.ROW_ID = G.ACTIVITY_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    select DISTINCT PC.X_RESEARCH
    , P.PR_EMP_ID as E_PER_ID
    , PC.CON_ID AS F_ROW_ID
    FROM PC
      INNER JOIN P  ON PC.POSTN_ID = P.ROW_ID
                   AND P.EMP_ID = P.PR_EMP_ID
      INNER JOIN CE ON CE.PAR_ROW_ID = P.EMP_ID
                 --AND CE.PAR_ROW_ID = P.PR_EMP_ID
    WHERE PC.X_RESEARCH = 'Y'
  ) XR ON XR.E_PER_ID = E.PER_ID
      AND XR.F_ROW_ID = F.ROW_ID
```

Cognos has trouble with `ISNULL`.  You'll have more luck with `COALESCE`.
Your `X_RESEARCH` value will only be `Y` when `P.EMP_ID = P.PR_EMP_ID`.
`dbo.S_CONTACT` is still not in the FROM clause, so this will still fail.

I usually use 3 namespaces directly under the main namespace for the project:

- Physical Layer
- Business Layer
- Presentation Layer

But this is usually for data marts.  What you are trying to do may use this pattern, but I'll not be using the Presentation Layer here.

Right-click on Physical Layer and use the "Import Metadata Wizard..." to have Cognos create the query subjects from your database (F, G, E, P, PC, CE).  It looks like you already did this step.

In the Business Layer, create a query subject for each of the physical query subjects.  They should be "model" query subjects.

Create the relationships between the business query subjects.

(Those last two steps may not be needed.  You may be able to use the physical layer to meet the same need.  But doing it this way may make it easier to recover from database changes in the future.)

Create a query subject that combines P, PC, and CE (I called the subquery XR above).  Add the filter `PC.X_RESEARCH = 'Y'` to this one.

Create the relationships between XR, F, and E.

Create a query subject that contains your final output.

Comment: thanks for all the details! i had already fixed this in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a layered approach in Framework?

**For example first layer, lets call this import** 
Would be the tables like P,PC,E and how they are joined and any filters
Creating data source query subjects at this level
the SQL for Query Subject PC would be

```
Select * from PC
```

then add filter -

```
X_Research = 'Y'
```

**The next namespace layer would be the calculations, we could call this the dev layer**

All of the data items that an author would want
Creating model source query subjects at this level and adding data items from the import layer or creating calculations

```
Name: Activity ID
Expression: Import.G.Activity_ID
```

**We could add a third layer that is for presentation**

Which has shortcuts from the dev layer to make the model more durable (design language vs label changes)

Let me know if you like this idea I can add more details on how to assemble this